# Preview bug in Cura 4.10.0

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I am interested in 3D printing projects and I use the Cura program for that purpose. Lately, when I preview my models in the Cura program to prepare for printing, I encounter an error and my prints come out distorted. I am using version Cura 4.10.0. Does anyone have experience with this version? Could there be an issue with the integrity or the geometric compatibility of my files in terms of dimensions and size? If anyone has experienced a similar problem, could you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a fairly old version of UltiMaker Cura, you should try a more recent version of Cura to test if it happens in the newer version as well.

Currently, at the time of writing, the latest version of Cura is 5.3.1.

Comment: I had not encountered such a problem before. While newer versions are usually designed to improve issues in previous versions, it doesn't necessarily mean that the current version is inherently weaker. Thank you for your recommendation, and I will give it a try.